# Angular material io predefined theme color

Tags: angular, colors, angular-material, themes

How do I access the color variables ( $primary, $accent, $warn, $foreground, $background) in scss file from a predefined  angular theme @angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'?

Comment: you can follow this guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

Once a sass file has been compiled to css, there is no more notion of variable inside that css file, so you won't be able to retrieve variables like `$primary` from `deeppurple-amber.css`.

If you look at the [scss source file](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss) for the `deeppurple-amber` theme, you can find the definition for `$primary` and other variables

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);
$accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
```

The `mat-palette` function and the base palette colors are  available in your project from `'~@angular/material/theming'`;

So to retrieve the palettes and colours, you can create try this:

**Step #1** Create a file `mat-vars.scss` file

**mat-vars.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
//And then retrieve the palette

$myPrimaryPaletteVariable : mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);
$myAccentPaletteVariable : mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);

//Retrive the colors you need
$myPrimaryColor : mat-color($myPrimaryPaletteVariable);
```

**Step #2** In your components scss files, just import that new file and use the variables

**component.scss**

```
@import '../../mat-vars';//ensure path is correct
.myText
{
    color: $myPrimaryColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I hope this will help others same as it helped me

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

create _variable.scss

```
// Import material theming functions
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Create your Sass color vars
$primary: mat-color($app-primary);
$accent: mat-color($app-accent);
$warn: mat-color($app-warn);
```

Import _variables.scss to the component's sass file where you want to use it.

```
@import "~_variables.scss";
.selected {
  background-color: $accent;
}
```

Don’t forget to include the theme.scss in the .angular-cli.json file:

```
{
...
  "apps": [{
  ...
  "styles": ["_variables.scss"]
  }]
  ...
}
```

if u still didn't get please go through this link
https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/how-to-use-angular-material-2-sass-variables-in-your-components-76ce0203f126

Comment: The above solution is applicable for the custom theme .but I've imported predefined angular theme and not sure about the way to initialize $app-primary, $app-accent and  $app-warn..