# How to get the button colors from the prebuilt themes?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have referenced some prebuilt themes:

```
.purple-theme {
  $mat-purple-primary: mat-palette($mat-purple, 100);
  $mat-purple-accent: mat-palette($mat-purple, 500);
  $mat-purple-warn: mat-palette($mat-purple, 900);
  $mat-purple-theme: mat-light-theme($mat-purple-primary, $mat-purple-accent, $mat-purple-warn);
  @include angular-material-theme($mat-purple-theme);
}

.deep-purple-theme {
  $mat-deep-purple-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple, 100);
  $mat-deep-purple-accent: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple, 500);
  $mat-deep-purple-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple, 900);
  $mat-deep-purple-theme: mat-light-theme($mat-deep-purple-primary, $mat-deep-purple-accent, $mat-deep-purple-warn);
  @include angular-material-theme($mat-deep-purple-theme);
}
```

And I need to feed an array to a theme roller.

The array item is typed as:

```
export interface ThemeMenuOption {

  backgroundColor: string;
  buttonColor: string;
  headingColor: string;
  label: string;
  value: string;

}
```

I could hard code the array like:

```
{
  "backgroundColor": "#fff",
  "buttonColor": "#ffc107",
  "headingColor": "#673ab7",
  "label": "Deep Purple & Amber",
  "value": "deeppurple-amber"
},
```

But I'd like to get that information from the themes themselves.

Version: `^9.2.2` of the `@angular/material` dependency.

UPDATE:

I hoped to use interpolation so as to build the variables names:

```
@mixin createTheme($name) {
  $primary: mat-palette($mat-#{$matName});
  $accent: mat-palette($mat-#{$matName});
  $warn: mat-palette(#{$mat-$matName});
  .#{$name}-light-theme {
    $light-theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
    @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
  }
  .#{$name}-dark-theme {
    $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
  }
}
```

but it's [not yet possible](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1778) and the above function fails on `$mat-#{$matName}`

UPDATE:
I could get some theme background colors, but I'd like to have the button colors and the heading colors for each theme. The trouble is I get the same button colors and the heading colors for all the themes. The background colors are different though.

```
$prebuiltThemeVariables: (
  $mat-purple-light-theme,
  $mat-deep-purple-light-theme,
  $mat-indigo-light-theme,
  $mat-pink-light-theme,
  $mat-red-light-theme,
  $mat-blue-light-theme,
  $mat-light-blue-light-theme,
  $mat-cyan-light-theme,
  $mat-teal-light-theme,
  $mat-green-light-theme,
  $mat-light-green-light-theme,
  $mat-lime-light-theme,
  $mat-yellow-light-theme,
  $mat-amber-light-theme,
  $mat-orange-light-theme,
  $mat-deep-orange-light-theme,
  $mat-brown-light-theme,
  $mat-grey-light-theme,
  $mat-blue-grey-light-theme
);

@function get-theme-element-color($mat-theme, $element, $is-background: true) {
  @if $is-background {
    $palette: map-get($mat-theme, background);
    @return map-get($palette, $element);
  } @else {
    $palette: map-get($mat-theme, foreground);
    @return map-get($palette, $element);
  }
}

@function get-theme-background-color($mat-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($mat-theme, primary);
  @return mat-color($primary);
}

@function get-theme-button-color($mat-theme) {
  @return get-theme-element-color($mat-theme, "status-bar");
}

@function get-theme-heading-color($mat-theme) {
  @return get-theme-element-color($mat-theme, "app-bar");
}

// Output some colors for the themes
@each $name in $prebuiltThemeVariables {
  @debug "------------!";
  @debug get-theme-background-color($name);
  @debug get-theme-button-color($name);
  @debug get-theme-heading-color($name);
}
```

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716972/angular-material-io-predefined-theme-color/61848229#61848229

Comment: It shows that the `mat-color()` function allows to get a color. But how to get the 3 colors I need ? And how to get the theme name and id ?